# Nautilus odt thumbnails gone after BleachBit

Tags: nautilus, libreoffice, thumbnails, odt

Nautilus used to generate thumbnails for .odt documents before I cleaned the pc with BleachBit and now I can't get it to work again. Any ideas?

Here's what I cleaned:

[image]

Comment: Hahaha, I did the edit for you. Nice HTML comment :)

Comment: Thanks! Still not 10 rep, can't post images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 4 hours of searching I solved the problem by installing:
`libgsf-bin` 

and restarting nautilus.

Comment: I almost put that in my answer. If that fixed it, you must be running 11.x, no?

Comment: I'm running 16.04 must have uninstalled that somehow. I can only accept the answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache/thumbnails
sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
```

And restart Nautilus

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work.